# Make a MenuItem non selectable in WPF

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a WPF application where I was suppose to add an "empty" item when nothing is there in the menu.

I have implemented it but I want to know how to make that empty item as non select-able whenever mouse over is there while for other menu it should work normally.

Kindly suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set [`IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) for `MenuItem` to false:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether this element is enabled in the user interface.

Example:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Favorites">
    <MenuItem Header="Empty" 
              IsEnabled="False" />

    <MenuItem Header="AnotherItem" 
              IsEnabled="True" />
    ...
</MenuItem>
```

Also you can try set [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `MenuItem` to false:

> Gets or sets a value that declares whether this element can possibly be returned as a hit test result from some portion of its rendered content.

Example:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Favorites">
    <MenuItem Header="Empty" 
              IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    ...
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anatoliy.Can you please tell if how to set it from code behind as I am adding "Empty item" from my viewmodel.cs FavoriteNodes.Add(new FavViewItem("Empty",true));

Comment: @user3408980: Why do you not indicated it at once in your question? And that means `FavViewItem("Empty", true)`?

Comment: Yeah and sorry for the inconvenience .

Comment: @user3408980: In code-behind try set this property like this: `MyMenuItem.IsHitTestVisible = false;` and `MyMenuItem.IsEnabled=false;`.